# Hiding the form while printing - strange behavior

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a form with a button that allows the user to print the selected sheet. Her absolutely minimized form is below.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
    lblHideCounter = lblHideCounter + 1
    Me.Hide
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
    Me.Show False
    lblShowCounter = lblShowCounter + 1
    MsgBox "bntHide_Click, Show Counter: " & lblShowCounter
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    MsgBox "UserForm_Terminate, Show Counter: " & lblShowCounter
End Sub
```

So that the form does not disturb the user when the printing dialog box is displayed, I decided to hide it and then show it back after printing. However, I noticed a rather unexpected behavior. Well, if the form is displayed in modal mode, the code that follows the `Show` command of the form will be run only after the form is finally closed (even after `UserForm_Terminate` event). If, on the other hand, the form is displayed in modeless mode, such a problem does not occur.

For some reasons, however, I would like my form to be displayed in modal mode. However, I am concerned that this behavior may result in problems (e.g. stack utilization?), if the user repeatedly presses print without closing the mold.

Can this be solved in some other way? For example, is it possible somehow (without using the `Hide` method) to hide the form while the print dialog is displayed and then display it again (without using the `Show` method)? Or maybe I shouldn't worry about this problem?

The file with example code can be downloaded from [here.](https://download.wetransfer.com/eugv/8ac5c9ed04ae00dabed599cdcec996af20220502122606/f51b1ab505c79858419b7d827e4e6f9aae0290ac/PrintTest.xlsb?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NTE0OTQ0NjIsImV4cCI6MTY1MTQ5NTA2MiwidW5pcXVlIjoiOGFjNWM5ZWQwNGFlMDBkYWJlZDU5OWNkY2VjOTk2YWYyMDIyMDUwMjEyMjYwNiIsImZpbGVuYW1lIjoiUHJpbnRUZXN0Lnhsc2IiLCJ3YXliaWxsX3VybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zdG9ybS1pbnRlcm5hbC5zZXJ2aWNlLmV1LXdlc3QtMS53ZXRyYW5zZmVyLm5ldC9hcGkvd2F5YmlsbHM_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.6WXrLGCbNVODfDqXApATaIlXFgrgLRD6VwjlL7bnbSQ&cf=y).

Comment: I think we need to see the calling part as well.

Comment: The form is called in the `Workbook_Open` event `UserForm1.Show`